# Modify IP header from an UDP socket before calling sendto()

Tags: c++, sockets

Hi I am currently learning socket programming with C++ and for testing purposes I want to modify the reserved bit in the IP header of an UDP package before sending data with the socket.

My current code looks like this:

```
if((sock_udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket error");
        return(-1);
    }

    strcpy(buffer, "Hello");
    int length = strlen(buffer) +1;

    destaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton(ip, &destaddr.sin_addr);
    destaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    // Can I somehow modify the IP header here?

    if(sendto(sock_udp, buffer, length, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&destaddr, sizeof(destaddr)) >= 0){
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, according to RFC 791 for IPv4 flags:

> Bit 0: reserved, must be zero

So you should avoid changing that.

But if your application actually requires it, than you cannot use a typical `SOCK_DGRAM`, but instead you have to use a `SOCK_RAW`, which allows build your own complete packet. The main disadvantage is that you have to fill Ethernet header and calculate checksums (for IP and UDP header). Also application using `SOCK_RAW` requires root privileges or `CAP_NET_RAW` capability.

For more information on `SOCK_RAW` you can check the man page `packet`. Online version [here](https://linux.die.net/man/7/packet).